# Merge two class objects in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to merge two class objects like the following

```
Class College{ 
      name,
      collegeName,
      students(Array)
}
```

I am creating two objects for this class named **objCollegeA** and **objCollegeB**.

If I am assigning the following values for these objects

```
objCollegeA.name = @"name1"
objCollegeA.collegeName = @"collegeName2"
objCollegeA.students = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",nil];
```

and for second object I am assigning the following values

```
objCollegeB.name = @"name1"
objCollegeB.collegeName = @"collegeName2"
objCollegeB.students = nil;//Here this array is nil
```

Now I need to merge these two objects like the following

`objCollegeA + objCollegeB => objCollegeA with Values {@"name1",@"collegeName2", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",nil];}`

That means I need to merge the tow objects and replace the nil values with values in the second object and return. Is there any way to do this in objective C?

Thanking you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Are name and collegeName properties' values always same for those two objects????

Comment: yes both are two different objects of the same class

Comment: Hey i am asking, @"name1" and @"collegeName2" values are same for both two objects?? :)

Comment: See my answer if i understood u properly

Answer (score 0):

Are you always going to be setting the nil attributes of collegeA to those attributes of collegeB and leaving the non-nil as the same as they are in collegeA? If so, you can just do:

```
-(College)addCollege:(College *)collegeB {
    if (!self.name) self.name = collegeB.name;
    if (!self.collegeName) self.collegeName = collegeB.collegeName;
    if (!self.students) self.students = collegeB.students;
}
```

then you can call:

```
[collegeA addCollege:collegeB];
```

Note that this will set them to the same objects rather than copying the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your add method in the `College` class

```
- (void)add:(College*)obj
{
    if(name == nil)
    {
        name = obj.name;
    }
    if(collegeName == nil)
    {
        collegeName = obj.collegeName;
    }
    if(students == nil && obj.students != nil)
    {
        students = [NSArray arrayWithArray:obj.students];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question then first you need to modify this statement:

```
objCollegeA.students = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",nil];
```

Then `[objCollegeA.students addObjectsFromArray:objCollegeB.students];`

If you need to change objCollegeA.name with objCollegeB.name then do:

```
objCollegeA.name = objCollegeB.name;
```

and `objCollegeA.collegeName = objCollegeB.collegeName;`